# GLSL (iOS) function parameters not working correctly?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsl

texture color passed to function is not working inside a loop?

I am really confused about this, the first code is working, the second is not. does someone has an explanation for this behaviour? By just moving the texture lookup inside the function it is working, but it is not needed as xy do not change.

**Not Working: (output is black)**

```
float getDistance(vec3 point,vec4 n_0)
{
    float d=point.z;
    d+=0.1*(n_0.w);
    return(d);
}

void main()
{
   vec4 n_0;
   vec4 color;
   vec3 point;

   point=vec3(v_coord.x*1.0,v_coord.y*1.0,-1.0);

   n_0=texture2D(noise,vec2(point*1.0))*2.0-1.0;

   int i;
   float d=100.0;
   for(i=0;i<50;i++)
   {
       d=getDistance(point,n_0);
       if(d<0.001)break;

       point.z+=d;
   }

    gl_FragColor=clamp(vec4(d),0.0,1.0);
}
```

**Working: (output is a noise)**

```
float getDistance(vec3 point)
{
    vec4 n_0=texture2D(noise,vec2(point*1.0))*2.0-1.0;

    float d=point.z;
    d+=0.1*(n_0.w);
    return(d);
}

void main()
{
    vec4 n_0;
    vec4 color;
    vec3 point;

    point=vec3(v_coord.x*1.0,v_coord.y*1.0,-1.0);

    int i;
    float d=100.0;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
        d=getDistance(point);
        if(d<0.001)break;

        point.z+=d;
    }

    gl_FragColor=clamp(vec4(d),0.0,1.0);
}
```